# .htaccess allow from REMOTE_HOST

Tags: .htaccess, remote-host

l'm trying to set up an .htaccess file that will restrict access to a specific file, unless the request has come from the same server.

Here's what l expected to work (but it doesn't seem to):

```
<Files /some/secret/cron.php>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from %{REMOTE_HOST}
</Files>
```

In this instance l can't just hard code in the IP address of the server, as it changes/rolls over to other servers throughout the day.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `%{REMOTE_HOST}` in `Allow from`. Use it in a `mod_rewrite` rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=11.22.33.44
RewriteRule cron\.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Replace `11.22.33.44` by your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr 127.0.0.1 Allowed=1
<Files "/some/secret/cron.php">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from env=Allowed
</Files>
```